# Selectable IMG with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to create selectable images which are child elements in unordered lists. In other words I try to change background color of image when image is clicked.

I have following HTML with unordered lists:

```
<ul id="select-message-type" class="cm-message-types-menu cm-message-types-ul">
    <li id="all" class="cm-all-messages">
        <img src="Images/IMIcon.png" /><br />
        All
    </li>
    <li id="email" class="cm-message-type-icon-wrap">
        <img src="Images/IMIcon.png" /><br />
        Email
    </li>
    <li id="im" class="cm-message-type-icon-wrap">
        <img src="Images/IMIcon.png" /><br />
        IM
    </li>
    <li id="call" class="cm-message-type-icon-wrap">
        <img src="Images/IMIcon.png" /><br />
        Call
    </li>
    <li id="fax" class="cm-message-type-icon-wrap">
        <img src="Images/IMIcon.png" /><br />
        Fax
    </li>
</ul>
```

And Following CSS which I use to add select style:

```
#select-message-type .ui-selecting {
        background-color: azure;
    }

    #select-message-type .ui-selected {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

I initialize selectable with following JQuery:

```
$("#select-message-type").selectable();
```

These pictures are simple icons. Is it possible to change background-color when user click on that image. In other words, is it possible to implement JQuery UI selectable for these images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
#select-message-type .ui-selected img {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8p0cdrb5/3/)

Comment: But I noticed one issue. On your way, also is selected list. I want to avoid list to be selected. I want only change color on image, not on list element.

Comment: I thought using `filter: 'img'` would work, but I tried it and it didn't. I think it only allows immediate children to be selected, not elements further down.

Comment: My solution doesn't change the color of the `LI`, only the `IMG`, because I removed the `#select-message-type .ui-selected` CSS.

Comment: You mean only use img {...} ?